# Inline divs to make a progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I can put inline the two divs in order to make a progress bar?
I want that no matter the width the divs they stay together in a single line

I am using bootstrap and I know that I can use the one there but in my case the one of bootstrap dont help for my project.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-chart">
            <div class="panel-heading naranja">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Title</p>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="progress-line azul part-one" style="width:70%"></div>
                    <div class="progress-line amarillo part-two" style="width:30%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s5m9hb0g/

Comment: Alternate solution would be to make the progress remaining the background for one div: https://jsfiddle.net/s5m9hb0g/3/

Comment: but in that case what happend if I want 3 sections? @LawrenceJohnson

Comment: Well, that's a different question. :) If it were me, I'd use either the flex approach, tables, or absolute positioning depending on how you want the three to work and what your target browser requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

Make the parent of the two parts of the progress bar `display:flex;`. This will make both divs display on the same line.

```
.panel-body .col-xs-12{
  display:flex;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvx29o29/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` on `.part-one`, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5m9hb0g/1/)

```
.part-one{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helps, you're welcome :)